# Javafx won't play mp3s from a certain album

Tags: audio, javafx

I have a javafx program that looks a little something like this:

```
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

public class MusicPlayer
{
    MediaPlayer medplay;
    public void start()
    {
        String songDir = new File("/Users/myusername/Desktop/song.mp3").getAbsolutePath();
        Media med = new Media(new File(songDir).toURI().toString());
        medplay = new MediaPlayer(med);
        medplay.play();
    }

    public void pause()
    {
        medplay.pause();
    }

    public void resume()
    {
        medplay.play();
    }
}
```

I tested various different mp3s I have all of which are from the same source.  They are all 320kbs mp3s as well.  When I try any song from Sum 41's album 13 Voices (if that's relevant) it won't play.  Also Boston for some reason.  I'm not sure why these mp3s won't play as opposed to any other songs I have in mp3.  I am using the BlueJ IDE(it's for high school).  Is there anyway I can debug what happens start() is called, but no music starts playing?  I am open to moving this project into another IDE if anyone knows better how to debug there and it would help them help me.

Comment: I don't understand why you do `String songDir = new File("/Users/myusername/Desktop/song.mp3").getAbsolutePath();` and then do `new File(songDir).toURI().toString()`. Why not just do `File file = new File("/Users/myusername/Desktop/song.mp3"); Media med = new Media(file.toURI().toString());` <- this may not be related to your problem.

Comment: Does BlueJ show exceptions when they occur? You are not getting any error messages at all?  Also, please consider adding a [mcve] that demonstrates the error.

Comment: My bad Zephyr that was probably an oversight on my part.  I should have mentioned that there were no exceptions.  There were exceptions in the past when there was simply a typo in the directory of the file, but there are none now when the music simply doesn't play which is why I am so confused.

Comment: Honestly Sedrick it's because my high school computer science class has a semester long project and I'm learning this all for the first time so what ever is in the YouTube video gets put in my code, but I also do my best to make sure I understand why I do what I do because otherwise it's pointless.  I did just use your method and the functionality is the same, but the code is now more simple so thank you.  Unfortunately as you suspected this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry Zephyr I forgot to mention that yes this is not all of my code I apologize.  This program wouldn't run at all if it was just what I posted above.  As I understand a JavaFX program needs to extend Application and have a start(Stage stage) method.  I have another class that does so and all it does is create a new instance of my User interface that has a couple of buttons.  If I comment out the other classes and just import javafx.application.Application and javafx.stage.Stage and change my start() method to start(Stage stage) then it continues to act the same.  Same songs won't play.

Comment: I have discovered something new.  All the files that won't play have something in common.  Their bitrates aren't exactly 320kbs.  They are bitrates like 320.045kbs or 320.029kbs.